# post launch task in visual studio code

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, task

I can launch task before debug my node app in vscode with preLaunchTask arg in launch.json but I can't find a way to launch task after the debug. Is there a way to do this in vscode like with the preLaunchTask?

Comment: in fact i want to delete node files after debug (.env, envent.json, ...)

Comment: you want this task to run after your debug session has completed or after it has started?

Comment: @Stewart_R i want to run it after the session is ended

Comment: Already entered as issue: [#2405 postLaunchTask would be very useful ](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/2405)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

v1.22 just added a `postDebugTask` , [release notes: postDebugTask](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_22#_postdebugtask-in-launchjson).

> We have added postDebugTask support in launch.json. This task is run
>   after a debug session finishes. Similar to preLaunchTask, you can
>   reference tasks in your tasks.json by a name. Here's an example of a
>   launch configuration using a postDebugTask:

```
{
    "name": "Attach to node server",
    "type": "node",
    "request": "attach",
    "port": 8008,
    "preLaunchTask": "Start Server",
    "postDebugTask": "Your delete task here"
}
```